# How to center and fill main in html/css?

Tags: html, css, program-entry-point

I am trying to create a website that looks as following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YHAs.jpg
The header is working, but I cannot get the "main" to work and tried several options. I tried to float a png as image-background to the center and also tried with display:inline-block and background-color:white. My code is as following:

```
HTML:    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Home - Portfolio Daniek</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="menutoggle.js"></script>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        </head>
        <body class="index">
            <nav class="clearfix">
                <ul class="clearfix">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">Over</a></li>
                    <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
        </nav>
        <main class="bg">
            <p>Hi</p>
        </main>
        </body>
CSS:
    .bg {
        margin-top: 10%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 90%;
        height: 90%;
        color: white;
        background-image: url('bg.png');
    }
```

Anybody got any solutions how to get this to work?

Comment: Please post a **complete** code example.

Comment: Follow this link http://jsfiddle.net/orahkd80/

Comment: use `rgb` background with `opacity` eg rgba(224, 234, 241, 0.69) `0.69` is `opacity`

Answer (score 1):

this Is a basic example of how one would do this:

```css
body{background:url('http://jasonlefkowitz.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Cute-Cats-cats-33440930-1280-800.jpg') no-repeat; background-size:100%; margin:0; overflow:hidden}
header{height:80px;width:100%; background:grey}
#main{width:90%; height:90%; position:absolute; background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5); margin:5%;}
```

```html
<body><header></header><div id="main"></div></body>
```

Click on the "Full Page" option to see how it would look

In your example you are using `background-color:white`, with that you could use `opacity:0.5` but that would make *everything* in main translucent. when you want transparencyhtml backgrounds use rgba. 50% transparency white in rgba: `background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `background: rgba(255,255,255,x);` where the "a" is for alpha ( transparency ) and "x" is the value between 0 and 1 like: `background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);` 50% transparent. This affect the background, if you want the content to be transparent as well use `opacity: x;` on `.main`.

**Edit:** New fiddle and css with responsive width and height

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/km0mz63q/3/

For a responsive height you need the boby to fill the entire document with `height: 100%` and a "pusher" element with a `min-height: 100%;`. In my exemple the `.container` push the footer to the bottom of the page. The negative margin on `.container` is important and must be equal to the footer height, it allows the footer to overlap the "pusher" ( `.container` ). Note that the footer need to be outside the pusher element to work.

```
html,body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
header{
    height: 60px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.container{
    background: url("http://www.world-finance-conference.com/sites/default/files/new-york-city-wallpaper.jpg") center center;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%; /* Set the container min height to 100% */  

    margin-bottom: -100px; /* !IMPORTANT - Must be equal to the footer height */

}
.container:after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
}
.main{
    width: 90%; /* change this for your desired width */
    padding: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5); /* rgba(): rgb is the color ( red, green, blue) and the "a" is for alpha ( transparency ) */
    height: 400px; /* change this for your custom height */
}
footer{
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

Also changed the html:

```
<div class="container">
    <header>This is header</header>
    <div class="main">This is main</div>
</div>
<footer> 
    This is footer
</footer>
```

You can also set the .container to `height: 100vh; /* vh: Viewport Height */` but I'm not sure if it's supported by all browsers.

Comment: The solution almost works, however the screen is not entirely filled and there is a black bar underneath the footer. Do you have any solution? Tried changing the pixels in %, but that doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: You want to fill the entire screen with the transparent element or the background image ? & I don't see any black bar under my footer exemple. Can you make a fiddle of your issue, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: I just copied the code from your fiddle, but I have a printscreen: http://i.imgur.com/ccsDAT6.jpg   It's about the white bar between the footer and the bottom of the screen. Do you know how I can make the entire page more "responsive" so it automatically adjusts to my/any resolution? Tried to play around with percentages, but that doesn't solve it.